# AO map shines at a certain angle of view

Tags: texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

I have been baking maps for this calculator assignment that I have been working on for a while. AO map seems to be working well but at some view angles, it shines where it is supposed to be dark as seen in the image editor. I have baked AO maps a couple of times before but have never seen something like this. Do you have any idea why is this happening?

[image: AO Map Shining bright like a diamond]